# Does Python interpreter return memory back to OS or not?

Tags: python, memory-management

upd. memory_profiler shows the resource usage of the code that is being running, not interpreter.

I'm trying to figure out whether python interpreter returns memory back to OS or not. I read some that Python process keeps memory allocated and will use it later for new data. But [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) shows that memory is being returned. I'm confused.

I do this:

**memprof.py**

```
import time

from memory_profiler import profile


def func2():
    lst = list(range(1_000_000))
    time.sleep(10)


@profile()
def func1():
    lst = list(range(1_000_000))
    func2()
    time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    aa = func1()
```

Run:

```
mprof run memprof.py
```

The output:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    11     38.3 MiB     38.3 MiB           1   @profile()
    12                                         def func1():
    13     77.0 MiB     38.6 MiB           1       lst = list(range(1_000_000))
    14     77.3 MiB      0.3 MiB           1       func2()
    15     77.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       time.sleep(10)
```

To see time-based memory usage run:

```
mprof plot
```

The result:

[image]

So does python interpreter return memory back to OS or not?

Comment: The Python profiler shows the resource usage of the code you are running, not that of the hosting Python process.

Comment: I suspected that fact

Answer (score 0):

memory_profiler shows the resource usage of the code that is being running, not interpreter's.